# Use a Timeout when receiving data from WSS connection (node js)

Tags: node.js, websocket, timeout, settimeout

when I have a WSS connection active, I receive data all 3 to 5 seconds. However, as it is often the same data (only changes each 30 to 60 seconds), I would like to use some kind of a timeout or interval, so that I only receive new data every 30 seconds.

I couldn’t find any solutions yet, as my search mostly provided solutions when you create a WSS yourself, instead of just receiving the data as a client.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: could you share some code? how are you receiving the data?